# Is it illegal to buy derivatives on your own assets?

Tags: united-states, law, derivatives

Is it illegal to buy derivatives on your own assets? Such as student loans you owe, or your own mortgage?

Answer (score 6):

No, but it's not possible, at least not for the two you cite. My mortgage happens to belong to a bank that held it. It was not collateralized into a CDO or other mortgage security. But, say it were. My mortgage would be one of many, representing a small fraction of the total security, maybe 1% or less. By finding out which CDO owns it to buy a derivative, what would my motivation be?

Student Loans are not permitted to default, they are backed by the government and the debt cannot be discharged although certain employment will offset the debt. Therefore a derivative wouldn't gain you too much, and the same goes for identifying which loan pool owns your specific debt.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're getting confused between assets and liabilities, your 'own assets' as you put are to you liabilities they are however assets to someone else.

For example your mortgage is a liability to you but an asset to person that owns the mortgage.

Thus the question you are really asking is if you can buy derivatives on your own Liabilities?

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely not illegal (disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, don't take legal advice from some guy on the internet, etc. etc. :), in fact there are strategies that explicitly prescribe doing this - like "[covered call writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covered_call)". So you can have derivatives on assets you own.

What you described however is not possible - for two reasons already described in other comments: a) nobody produces derivatives on a single loan b) your loan is not your asset, it's bank's asset and your liability.

Comment: Well, people do produce derivatives and related instruments on a single loan... just not a single *retail* loan like student debt. See also: *credit default swaps*.

Comment: of course, I meant single loan of a regular person :)

Answer (score 1):

An interesting question. In some sense, there are cases where you're **required** to buy derivatives on your assets, namely Private Mortgage Insurance. But the beneficiary is the lender and the amount insured is the amount of the mortgage, commonly known as the **insured interest**. Most insurance limits payouts to the insured interest you have at stake.

But we know that **credit default swaps** (CDS) didn't have that requirement; you can buy a CDS without owning the bond. There's certainly a moral hazard issue when you can buy a home and insure the mortgage for more than it costs you to default on it, and you would have to read the contract and prospectus very carefully. But assuming you found your mortgage in a CDO, and yours was the only asset giving value to it, I suppose its possible to buy a ton of credit swaps on it.

But making this work in court would be tricky. You'd refuse payment, which would lead the CDO to stop paying money. The loss of money would trigger a CDS payment. Then the CDO sues you for the cash, and you pay out. So then they pay out to holders, and then it gets fuzzy for me. I figure the CDS has rights to recover that payment, and then your payment enters a strange loop where it's both paid and unpaid at the same time.